# what does $S \times T $ (read as $S$ cross $T$) or $S \times S$ (read as $S$ cross $S$) in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to know the mathematical implication of the cross symbol. Consider $S$ as set of states and $T$ as the set of events. What would be the mathematical meaning if you have $S \times T \times S $ ?

I read as "Set–stage: Fxr denotes that set x “is formed at” stage r;". I couldn't follow this explanation. Can someone provide a proper reference link or explanation?
I encountered this while analyzing a state transition system.

Comment: (1) The `\times` command produces $\times$ which is a much better alternative to ` X ` (in particular because $\rm\LaTeX$ ignores spaces in math-mode). and (2) it would be helpful if you give an actual reference of where you've seen the $\times$ symbol. It generally means the Cartesian product of two sets, but it seems that you're looking to understand something more specific, and it will be better if you just ask about *that*.

Comment: $S\times T$ is the set of ordered pairs $(s,t)$, where $s\in S$ and $t\in T$. It has $|S|\cdot |T|$ elements.